# Excel Macro: Setting a variable for a workbooks location?

Tags: vba, excel, macros, copy

I need to write a macro script that will copy data from one xml workbook and paste the values to another workbook. I've written the below macro that works fine, but i need to run this every week for several different documents so it means i have to replace the document name for each run.

Here's what i have so far:

```
Sub copying()

''''''Section 1''''''
Workbooks("Results_2561").Activate 'workbook i'm copying from
Range("B27:B41").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Overall_Results").Activate 'workbook i'm pasting to
Range("G2").PasteSpecial

''''''Section 2''''''
Workbooks("Results_2561").Activate
Range("C27:C41").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Overall_Results").Activate
Range("C2").PasteSpecial

''''''Section 3''''''
Workbooks("Results_2561").Activate
Range("I28:I40").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Overall_Results").Activate
Range("G17").PasteSpecial

''''''Section 4''''''
Workbooks("Results_2561").Activate
Range("J28:J40").Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("Overall_Results").Activate
Range("C17").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

...
and that's only half the script. Is there a way i can declare a variable at the start and set it as the Workbooks file path so i can call that instead of typing and retyping it over and over again?
Preferably without using something like

```
Dim book1 as Workbook
Set book1 = Workbooks.Open("C://Results_2561.xlsm")
```

..as this keeps opening and closing the document when i run the script.

Thanks

Comment: something like this: use a `String` , `Dim StrPath as String` , `StrPath = "C://Results_2561.xlsm"` , and `Set book1 = Workbooks.Open(StrPath )`

Comment: How about opening a file dialog at the beginning of the macro?

Comment: better avoid using `Activate` , `Selection` and `Select`. You could have one **BIG** `With Workbooks("Results_2561")` in the start of your code, then to copy use `.Range("B27:B41").Copy` , to PasteSpecial `Workbooks("Overall_Results").Range("G2").PasteSpecial xlValues` (you need another parametr if you are using `PasteSpecial `

Comment: or perhaps define an input box variable, and type the name of the file it will come from in the input box. Then use that stored variable in the opening of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're only interested in copying values you could use this helper `Sub`

```
Sub CopyValues(rngToCopyFrom As Range, rngToCopyTo As Range)
    With rngToCopyFrom
        rngToCopyTo.Resize(.Rows.COUNT, .Columns.COUNT).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

to be exploited in your main code like follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim wsTo As Worksheet

    Set wsTo = Workbooks("Overall_Results").ActiveSheet '<--| set the worksheet to paste values to
    With Workbooks("Results_2561").ActiveSheet '<--| reference the worksheet to copy values from
        CopyValues .Range("B27:B41"), wsTo.Range("G2")
        CopyValues .Range("C27:C41"), wsTo.Range("C2")
        CopyValues .Range("I28:I40"), wsTo.Range("G17")
        CopyValues .Range("J28:J40"), wsTo.Range("C17")
    End With
End Sub
```

should your relevant workbooks have more than one sheet, then just substitute

```
ActiveSheet
```

with

```
Worksheets("myRelevantShetName") '<--|change "myRelevantShetName" to the actual name of the relevant worksheet in each workbook
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please see also edited code for further reduction of typing efforts and a more robust approach for range references with explicit worksheet qualification. If my answer solved your question you may want to mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to Activate workbook every time when you want to copy/paste something. Just declare it in `Range()` property, for example:

```
''''''Section 1''''''
Workbooks("Results_2561").Sheets(1).Range("B27:B41").Copy
Workbooks("Overall_Results").Sheets(1).Range("G2").PasteSpecial
```

You can set Workbook as variable like:

```
Sub copying()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks("Results_2561")
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Overall_Results")

''''''Section 1''''''
wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B27:B41").Copy
wb2.Sheets(1).Range("G2").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Finally, as @A.S.H suggested, you can add a file dialog where you point which files you want to use. I have put it in some function (don't forget to put it in the same project as your `copying` macro):

```
Function strPath() As String
Dim intResult As Integer
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Title = "Select file"
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).Show
If intResult <> 0 Then
    strPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker).SelectedItems(1)
End If
End Function
```

So your final code for Section 1 would look like:

```
Sub copying()
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
MsgBox "Show file to copy form."
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(strPath())
MsgBox "Show file to paste in."
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(strPath())

''''''Section 1''''''
wb1.Sheets(1).Range("B27:B41").Copy
wb2.Sheets(1).Range("G2").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you so much!